# React useEffect hook infinity loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, use-effect

I keep encountering an infinity loop when trying to use the useEffect hook to fetch and set data. ive tried 3 variations of the hook and they all produce a loop, how do i stop this from happening?

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token).then(response => setPosts(response))
        })()
    })
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token).then(response => setPosts(response))
        })()
    },[])
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token).then(response => setPosts(response))
        })()
    },[profile.posts])
```

EDIT: Here is the PostApi.getPostsByUser code

```
getPostsByUser: (userId, token) => {
        return(
            axios
            .get("/api/posts/by/" + userId, {
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("Posts by User");
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        )
    }
```

EDIT: Function component code:

```
const Posts = () => {
    const [{auth}] = useAuth();
    const [{profile},, setPosts] = useProfile()

    useEffect(() => {
        PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token)
        .then(response => setPosts(response));
    },[]);

    console.log(profile)
    return(
        <div className="User-Post">
            <div className="New-Post">
                <NewPost />
            </div>
            <div className="User-Posts-Content">
                {
                    profile.posts ? profile.posts.map((item, key) => {
                        return <Post post={item} key={key} />
                    }) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Posts
```

Comment: I don't think the second variation can cause you an infinite loop since the effect will only run once.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri you would think that but sadly it does

Comment: You should pass api function as dependency to useEffect.

`useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token).then(response => setPosts(response))
        })()
    },[PostApi.getPostsByUser])`

Comment: Can we see your PostApi code?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I updated the op and added the code there

Comment: Did you check my comment?

Comment: @MichałK yes, still nothing

Comment: @josephD and no it is not

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor is `profile` always changing in your `console.log()`?

Comment: @JosephD yes, it’s constantly fetching and then changing the state endlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
const [auth] = useAuth();
const [profile, setPosts] = useState();


const setPosts = posts => { setPosts(state => ({ ...state, profile: { 
             ...state.profile, posts: posts } })) } 


getPostsByUser: (userId, token) => {
        return(
            axios
            .get("/api/posts/by/" + userId, {
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                }
            });
    }
```

and

```
useEffect(() => {
            PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token)
            .then(response => setPosts(response.data));     
     },[]);
```

Comment: Still endless looping

Comment: Can you post setPosts function

Comment: `const setPosts = posts => {
        setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            profile: {
                ...state.profile,
                posts: posts
            }
        }))
    }`

Comment: Post  your  functional component declaration  in question

Comment: What is useProfile?  may be useState ?

Comment: useProfile is a custom hook i made thats used to update the global profile state. setPosts is one of the methods in it. if you would like to see it all i heres the github repo [link](https://github.com/anthonyg56/pickpack)

Comment: Can you remove all your staff with useProfile and setPosts.. you have to look in console dev I think you have wrong using of setposts and setstate... Strange case

Comment: It is very strange, this should work yet I have still to find a work around. I found out the problem is in the setPosts hook

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const get = async () => {
    const response = await PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token);
    setPosts(response);
  }
  get();
},[]);
```

Comment: Sadly it’s still looping, I don’t understand why

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor if it's still looping with an empty dependency array, it means the whole component is getting destroyed and re-created on render, or that the loop is caused by either the `useAuth` or the `usePost` hook

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ... and the simplest solution too

```
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
              PostApi.getPostsByUser(auth.user._id, auth.token).then(response => setPosts(response))
          })()
      },toggle)
```